# Qualys Scanner in AWS - opening outbound FW ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm setting up Qualys scanner in Amazon Web Services in an environment that restricts outbound access to the internet from the VPC. It does so completely.

So I'll need to open a ticket to get the outbound access it needs, and I have to specify each IP that the Qualys server will need to connect to.

I'm seeing this message in the logs:

```
Starting crond: 
Preparing scanner personalization
About to test connectivity to qualysguard.qualys.com
Error: No connectivity to qualysguard.qualys.com - please fix.
About to test connectivity to qualysguard.qualys.com
```

My question is, do I need to open up access to just that one domain? Or do I have to open up access to more than that one domain. I have to be specific and cannot use wildcards in the request. This environment is extremely locked down for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can restrict the access of your environment but also to allow certain ports.
AWS does not resolve on DNS names, so make sure you get the set of IP addresses that are to be allowed for access

1. Use ELB - allow certain ports and permit access for those ports/ip addresses
2. Port address translation - look in for applications that will allow particular ports from a set of ip addresses
3. move your application to public subnet and allow the specific port/ip addresses

Comment: OK thanks, but I really just need to know if I need to open access to more URL's than the one I list above. I will be requesting access to the IP not the URL. 

All of our apps store financial info so we don't have the luxury of moving the app to a more open environment. ALL of our environments in AWS are locked down this way. I don't need advice on how to lock down / or provide access to different IP's / ports. All of that is handled by another team. 

Thanks